# Visual Studio Express 2013, new installation wont launch - The application has failed to start because its side by side configuration is incorrect

Tags: configuration, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-express, side-by-side

I tried installing Visual Studio 2013 Express for **Desktop** for the first time ever as I'm trying to get in to C# as Python doesn't really meet my needs. The installation ran fine, as I downloaded the ISO and mounted it to a virtual BD-ROM drive when the normal EXE wouldn't work. But now, when I go to run the program it tells me that:

> The application has failed to start because its side by side configuration is incorrect.

and doesn't allow me to run the program. I tried to run the installer again to repair the program but it basically reinstalled the whole thing and did nothing. Any help?

Comment: Have you googled the error? http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/error-the-application-has-failed-to-start-because/df019c0d-746e-42d0-ad68-465e18e3f3ef

Comment: Look in the Windows event log for a more detailed description of the problem.  Do expect your Windows install to be in poor condition if you couldn't get the EXE version of the installer going either.

Comment: Which Visual Studio Express edition did you actually install? (this might be important)

Comment: @L19 I have googled it but nothing useful came up. I'll try the linked solution soon when I get to a computer though. Thanks.

Comment: @jessehouwing Desktop, on Windows 7 SP1.

Comment: have you tried solution given by Samson sun in the post http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ba7e1d3b-25ac-4c72-b3fb-6bdaa7c6058f/vs2012-stopped-working-repair-caused-bsod-how-to-uninstall?forum=vssetup